# Counter allowing repetitions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

I have a Traffic Light Enum defining possible states:

```
class TrafficLightPhase(Enum):
    RED = "RED"
    YELLOW = "YELLOW"
    GREEN = "GREEN"
```

I poll a Traffic Light to get current state every second and I put the values in a `deque` with this function:

```
def read_phases():
    while running:
        current_phase = get_current_phase_phases()
        last_phases.append(current_phase)
        time.sleep(1)
```

I want to group sequences of the same state in order to learn traffic light phases timing.

I tried to use `Counter` class of `collections`, like this:

```
counter = collections.Counter(last_phases)
```

It groups very well different states, but I'm not able to know when next cycle starts. **Is there a similar data structure like `Counter` that allows repetitions?** so I can get results like:

```
Counter({
         'RED': 10,
         'GREEN': 10, 
         'YELLOW': 3,
         'RED': 10,
         'GREEN': 10, 
         'YELLOW': 3,
         'RED': 10,
         'GREEN': 10, 
         'YELLOW': 3
        })
```

instead of:
    Counter({
             'RED': 30,
             'GREEN': 30, 
             'YELLOW': 9
            })

Comment: use a list of lists or a list of tuples?

Comment: What's your exact input for the expected output your posted? Also it's not very clear what does `read_phases()` do? please add the real code completely and explain where you defined `last_phases` and where you call `collections.Counter(last_phases)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `itertools.groupby` for this. It will group contiguous runs of the same element, then you can check the length for each run.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> last_phases= ['red', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'red', 'green']
>>> [(key, len(list(group))) for key,group in groupby(last_phases)]
[('red', 2), ('yellow', 1), ('red', 2), ('green', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`collections.Counter` will not work here as it does not differentiate items by order.

I recommend you use `itertools.groupby`.

But, for reference, below is a solution using `collections.defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import islice, chain, zip_longest

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

last_phases= ['red', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'red', 'green']

c = 0
for i, j in zip_longest(last_phases, islice(last_phases, 1, None)):
    d[c][i] += 1
    if i != j:
        c += 1

res = list(chain.from_iterable(i.items() for i in d.values()))

[('red', 2), ('yellow', 1), ('red', 2), ('green', 1)]
```